The constructor Login(int, String, String, String, Date, String, String, int) is undefined
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/AQD6Sb8J.jpg)
I have this error and can't fix it. Please help me
My DbContext has also been connected successfully
My model part is as shown in the photo and the dal is also in the photo. I hope everyone can help me fix this error
The toString gets sets methods have also been added which are automatically generated by eclipse
I don't know how to fix that unspecified error. I hope someone can help me
(The constructor Login(int, String, String, String, Date, String, String, int) is undefined)
is this error

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So you have two Login classes? Which one do you call? I may assume the wrong one, hence itself.

Go into the class for which you are trying to create the object and define that constructor that you are calling to create the object.

This is because both classes are named Login. The IDE thinks that you are using the class Login that extends DBContext, which indeed does not have such a constructor. You can also see in the imports that the simple Login class has not been imported. In this case you can do 2 things.

Rename one of the Login classes.

Specify which Login class you want to use each time. When you type Login
these autocompletions should show up:

If i choose the other Login class it will be imported like this:

As you can see, Java understands it a different Login class because of its
path. You can tell this is not very easy to read, thats why its better to
go with option 1.


Full code i wrote to replicate you problem:
package project.model;

public class Login {
    public Login(String a , String b){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

This is the class your problem occured
package project.dao;

public class Login extends BDContext{
    public void check(){
        project.model.Login login = new project.model.Login("value","value");
    }
}

Hope this helps!
